# Dynamic loading of AngularJS view

Tags: angularjs, rest, view, angular-ui-router, partial

Is there a way to load the view that is exposed via Rest with UI-Router in AngularJS? 
The idea behind this is to have UI-Router request the partial from the Rest interface and then have the controller add the variables to $scope.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2553-loading-angularjs-components-after-your-application-has-been-bootstrapped.htm) is what you want to acieve

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am however just looking for an easy way to do a request to a Rest interface inside the config(where basically the view is defined) so I can pass the returned HTML to the resp. view.
The idea, again, is to not use an .html template but instead retrieve the data from a Rest interface.

Comment: really not very clear what you are asking. Perhaps code samples of your flow concept would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume 2 pages, index.html and details.html

in index.html

```
<script>
function ctr($scope,$http)
{
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "details.html"
    }).success(function (data, status){
      $("#content").empty();
      $("#content").append(x);
      var p = $("#content");
      $compile(p.contents())($scope);
    });
}
</script>
<div id="content">
put ur content here
</div>
```

in details.html

```
<script>
function ctrb($scope)
{
  $scope.details = "here is details";
}
</script>
<div ng-controller="ctrb">
  {{details}}
</div>
```

So the details will have own controller, and main controller also can access detail controller if u want.

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks, I will definitely try this!